# Please explain how this query work with "WHERE and AND"

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select d.department_id 
from departments d 
left join employees e on d.department_id = e.department_id
and e.department_id is null



select d.department_id
from departments d
left join employees e on d.department_id = e.department_id
where e.department_id is null
```

Answer (score 1):

In your second query:

```sql
select d.department_id
from departments d
left join employees e on d.department_id = e.department_id
where e.department_id is null
```

You are left joining `departments` to `employees`, which means that every record from `departments` will initially be retained, even if no match occurs.  However, the `WHERE` clause then filters off (read: removes) any record for which there was one or more matching employees.  As a result, this query may drop records from the left side of the join, despite what you might have intended.

On the other hand, in your first query:

```sql
select d.department_id
from departments d
left join employees e
    on d.department_id = e.department_id and
       e.department_id is null
```

The join condition also includes the null check, and there is no `WHERE` clause.  As a result, all department records would appear in the result set, whether or not they match the `employees` table.